# Showing synced lyrics of mp3 music in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I wrote a program that syncs the lyric of an MP3 song and displays the text as a subtitle when playing the song, but my code for this is too Unprofessional and weak. Is there a way to display it more professionally?
I tried this:

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

        Dim lines As String() = VTextBox1.Lines

        lines(lblLineNumber.Text) = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPositionString & "-" _
                & lblLineText.Text

        VTextBox1.Lines = lines

End Sub
```

result this:

```
00:08 - The situation is dire  
00:11 - But momma raised up a fighter
00:15 - It's all come down to the wire
```

Display lyric code:

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        Label6.Text = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPositionString

    End Sub  

    Private Sub Label6_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label6.TextChanged
        For Each T As String In VTextBox1.Lines
            If T.Contains(Label6.Text) = True Then
                Dim array As String = T
                Dim srt As String = array.Substring(array.IndexOf("-") + 1)

                lblDisplayLyric.Text = srt

            End If

        Next

    End Sub
```